# Is there a way to create a unique constraint on a column larger than 900 bytes?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, primary-key

I'm fairly new to SQL Server, so if anything I say doesn't make sense, there's a good chance I'm just confused by something. Anyway...

I have a simple mapping table. It has two columns, `Before` and `After`. All I want is a constraint that the `Before` column is unique. Originally it was set to be a primary key, but this created errors when the value was too large. I tried adding an `ID` column as a primary key and then adding `UNIQUE` to the `Before` column, but I have the same problem with the max length exceeding 900 bytes (I guess the constraint creates an index).

The only option I can think of is too change the `id` column to a checksum column and make that the primary key, but I dislike this option. Is there a different way to do this? I just need two simple columns.

Comment: What RDBMS? What are the column datatypes? Do they need to be that wide?

Comment: When you say 'checksum' are you talking about a hash?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL server. They are both nvarchar, and yes they need to be that wide.

Yes a hash. Checksum the column into its own column. Check uniqueness on that.

Comment: No, there is no way in SQL Server to do this. A `UNIQUE` constraint is always enforced via a unique index, and the max. size for any index entry is **900 bytes** - and it's a hard, system-wide limit - you cannot change / configure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of to guarantee uniqueness inside the database is to use an [INSTEAD OF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175158%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) trigger.  The link I provided to MSDN has an example for checking uniqueness. This solution will most likely be quite slow indeed, since you won't be able to index on the column being checked.

You could speed it up somewhat by using a computed column to create a hash, perhaps using the [HASHBYTES function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx), of the Before column.  You could then create a non-unique index on that hash column, and inside your trigger check for the negative case -- that is, check to see if a row with the same hash *doesn't* exist.  If that happens, exit the trigger. In the case there is another row with the same hash, you could then do the more expensive check for an exact duplicate, and raise an error if the user enters a duplicate value.  You also might be able to simplify your check by simply comparing both the hash value and the Before value in one EXISTS() clause, but I haven't played around with the performance of that solution.

(Note that the HASHBYTES function I referred to itself can hash only up to 8000 bytes.  If you want to go bigger than that, you'll have to roll your own hash function or live with the collisions caused by the CHECKSUM() function)

Comment: Can't the hashed value exceed the 900 byte limit of the index on it?

Comment: No, the point of the hash function is to yield a small, fixed-length (usually with HASHBYTES, it's 128 bits) number.

Comment: Oh awesome. I was testing out and was getting small values like I originally expected, but the HASHBYTES link says it returns a max of 8000 bytes and it threw me off. Thanks!